# How to invoke JavaScript function in window.open URL & Decrease the website body height

Tags: javascript, css, window.open

When I open a new browser window in JavaScript by `window.open()` method, I want to change the body’s height from the current script.

For example,

```
window.open("https://www.example.com", "_blank", "width=300,height=150");
```

But this only changes the window height to `150px`.

I want to be able to change the body height in the new window, using the script from the current/main window.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Here’s what I have so far:

```js
window.open("https://www.example.com", "_blank", "width=300,height=150");
```

Comment: What do you mean by “change the website height?”  I understand you don’t mean the window size, but I’m not understanding what you *do* mean.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ok let me explain you clearly , i mean <body style="height:10px"> , there i need to change body height from js script

Comment: You can access the web page from the window.open() instance. For example, `let win = window.open(…); win.document.body.style.height = “150px”`

Comment: I tried this too sir, but won't work , can you send any live sources? like this http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/JRqTy/3/

Comment: Are you trying to open a separate window or a new tab?

Comment: @FasalBasha You should show us what you've tried. We can't help you fix your code if you won't show it to us.

Comment: let myWindow = window.open("https://wp-developer.online/", "_blank");

let body = myWindow.document.body;

body.style.height = "10px";
    
  This is the example image , this image open a website as window.open ... example image : https://wp-developer.online/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/2023-02-04.png   I need to change height till that line ... is it possible ?

Comment: #ParkingMaster  Yes i am trying in new window

Comment: https://wp-developer.online/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/crop.png please refer this image

Comment: Well you’re code is opening the window in new tab. You can’t do this when you open it in a new tab.

Comment: we cant inject the js script after new  window open ?

Answer (score -1):

Similar to the `window` object in JavaScript, the return value of the function `window.open(…)` will return a window object also.

Here you can change everything in the window just like you would on the current page:

```js
let myWindow = window.open("https://www.example.com", "_blank", "");

let body = myWindow.document.body;

body.style.height = "10px";
```

This will open a window, **select the body** element from that window, and **modify the height** of it to be `10px` (or whatever you want).

Comment: I tired this too sir , but won't work , do you have any live examples like fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/JRqTy/3/